# What is the purpose of the root package.json in Lerna?

Tags: javascript, node.js, monorepo, lerna

What is the purpose of the dependencies in the root `package.json` in Lerna monorepo?

Since each package/microservice has it's own `package.json`, why should I have the `package.json`in the root directory?

If I install some dependency in the root level, each package inheritance it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See [Hoisting](https://lerna.js.org/docs/concepts/hoisting) in the Lerna documentation.

> the various packages often have many duplicate dependencies in their package.json files … Lerna can reduce the time and space requirements for numerous copies of packages in development and build environments, by "hoisting" dependencies up to the topmost, Lerna-project-level node_modules directory instead.

Comment: I see. So basically I cant install global dependencies that common to all the packages in the monorepo?

Comment: it's not just hoisting, you can install global deps in the root and execute them globally, for example I install ESLint and Jest globally and run 1 instance globally (some may argue it's better to run Jest/Lint per package but I prefer globally). Another point is if you add npm script running Lerna, they'll have to be defined in the root package.json